# Remove namespace from SOAP request and response

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I have a SOAP request similar to this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    ....
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <MyRequest>
    <Param>3</Param>
  </MyRequest>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and the response should be like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    ....
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <MyResponse>
    <Value>3234</Value>
    <Value>542</Value>
  </MyResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My problem is that my JAX-WS SOAP service expects a namespace e.g. xmlns="http://myapp.example.com" in `MyRequest`. It also adds this namespace to the `MyResponse` element too.

I have managed to write an Interceptor that will add my apps target namespace to the request message if it is blank. This works fine.

My issue right now is that I am not sure how to remove this namespace from the response message.

I know the best solution would be to have clients use namespaces, however this is not possible on the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

CXF comes with Transformation Feature, Please have look [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html)

A sample bean extract from page.

```
<bean id="transformFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.StaxTransformFeature">
  <property name="outTransformElements">
    <map>
      <!-- change "book" to "thebook" -->
      <entry key="book" value="thebook"/>

      <!-- drop the namespace from "book" -->
      <entry key="{http://books}book" value="book"/> 

      <!-- qualify "book" with "http://books" -->
      <entry key="book" value="{http://books}thebook"/> 

      <!--  change namespace to "http://books" for all the elements with the "http://book" namespace -->
      <entry key="{http://book}*" value="{http://books}*"/> 
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

That's pretty broad since we don't know what you are using, but if you can use Metro (JAX-WS) then you can take advantage of what they call **SOAPMessage Handler** (have a look [here](https://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html)). It works pretty much like a Servlet filter component.

Have something that `implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` and remove the namespace declaration(s) there.

Comment: Metro is an implementation of JAX-WS. OP is using CXF and JAX-WS as you can see in tags, and is asking about how to implement a handler